# How to implement Sklearn Metric in Keras as Metric?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, keras

Tried googling up, but could not find how to implement Sklearn metrics like cohen kappa, roc, f1score in keras as a metric for imbalanced data.

How to implement Sklearn Metric in Keras as Metric?

Comment: Can you write a wrapper on the sklearn function that takes in y_true and y_pred as the documentation states? https://keras.io/metrics/ --> check very bottom of page under "Custom metrics"

Comment: Tried thay, however sklearn requires numpy arrays and keras has tensors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Metrics in Keras and in Sklearn mean different things.

In Keras metrics are almost same as loss. They get called during training at the end of each batch and each epoch for reporting and logging purposes. Example use is having the loss 'mse' but you still would like to see 'mae'. In this case you can add 'mae' as a metrics to the model.

In Sklearn metric functions are applied on predictions as per the definition "The metrics module implements functions assessing prediction error for specific purposes". While there's an overlap, the statistical functions of Sklearn doesn't fit to the definition of metrics in Keras. Sklearn metrics can return float, array, 2D array with both dimensions greater than 1. There is no such object in Keras by the predict method.

Answer to your question:
It depends where you want to trigger:

1. End of each batch or each epoch
   You can write a custom callback that is fired at the end of batch.
2. After prediction
   This seems to be easier. Let Keras predict on the entire dataset, capture the result and then feed the y_true and y_pred arrays to the respective Sklearn metric.

Comment: I require end of each batch. Will try your method. Please share if any links. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Everything you need to live is in the confuse matrix. Calculate the confuse matrix and follow my formulas:

[image]

In practice, this is done as follows:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

NBC = NBC.fit(X_train,y_train)
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, NBC.predict(X_test))
tn, fp, fn, tp = cm.ravel()
print('tn: ',tn)
print('fp: ',fp)
print('fn: ',fn)
print('tp: ',tp)
print('------------------')
print(cm)
```

and now:

```
p_0 = (tn+)/(tn+fp+fn+)
print('p_0:',p_0)

P_class0 = ((tn+fp)/(tn+fp+fn+))*((tn+fn)/(tn+fp+fn+))
print('P_yes: ',P_yes)

P_class1 = ((fn+)/(tn+fp+fn+))*((fp+)/(tn+fp+fn+))
print('P_no: ',P_no)


pe = P_yes + P_no
print('pe: ',pe)

κ = (p_0-pe)/(1-pe)
print('κ: ',κ)
```

Comment: This is not the answer to the question.