# How to get Mean Absolute Errors (MAE) for deep learning model

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am working on a recommendation system using a deep autoencoder model. How can I define the **mean absolute error(MAE)** loss function, and use it to calculate the model accuracy.

Here is the model

```
model = deep_model(train_, layers, activation, last_activation, dropout, regularizer_encode, regularizer_decode)
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001), loss="mse", metrics=[  ] )
model.summary()
```

define the data-validate

```
data_valid =(train, validate)
```

```
hist_model = model.fit(x=train, y=train,
                  epochs=100,
                  batch_size=128,
                  validation_data= data_valid, verbose=2, shuffle=True)
```

Comment: loss=‘mae’ doesn’t work?

Comment: no its doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? It does work if you do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you can define it yourself:

```
import keras.backend as K

def my_mae(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.abs(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1) # -1 is correct, using None gives different result '''
```

then do this:

```
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=1e-2), loss=my_mae)
```

but it still a better idea to call the one implemented in keras, in this way:

```
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=1e-2), loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError(name="mean_absolute_error"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can you the scikit-learn function [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_error.html). This will return the mae of your prediction.
I suggest fitting the model as:

```
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001), loss="mae", metrics=[]) 
                           # instead of loss="mse"
model_history = model.fit(
   X_train,   # instead of: x=train, y=train
   y_train,   # why x and y are the same as 'train'?
   epochs=100,
   batch_size=128,
   validation_data=(X_test,y_test))
```

After train your model, make a prediction:

`predicton = model.predict(X_test)`

And get the MAE by:

`mae_error = mean_absolute_error(y_test, prediction)`

Comment: can you explain details, thank you! @BestDogeStackoverflow

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48567012/how-to-implement-sklearn-metric-in-keras-as-metric/48573176 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64181260/using-sklearn-macro-f1-score-as-a-metric-in-tensorflow-keras

Comment: I also think this the problem while @Karamo fit with `x=train, y=train`, maybe it is the reason that `loss="mae"` not works as it is?

Comment: @TrườngThuậnNguyễn the `x=train, y=train` are not the problem. Am using Autoencoder model, where the output is the reconstruction of the input. i did used the RMSE function on the model and the result is  `0.8010

Answer (score 0):

i did the used the RMSE to measure the model and the results were good. below the defined loss=masked_ms and metrics=[masked_rmse_clip] function

for the loss function

```
def masked_mse(y_true, y_pred):
       # masked function
       mask_true = K.cast(K.not_equal(y_true, 0), K.floatx())
       # masked squared error
       masked_squared_error = K.square(mask_true * (y_true - y_pred))
       masked_mse = K.sum(masked_squared_error, axis=-1) / K.maximum(K.sum(mask_true, axis=-1), 1)
       return masked_mse
```

for the metric

```
def masked_rmse_clip(y_true, y_pred):
        # masked function
        mask_true = K.cast(K.not_equal(y_true, 0), K.floatx())
        y_pred = K.clip(y_pred, 1, 5)
        # masked squared error
        masked_squared_error = K.square(mask_true * (y_true - y_pred))
        masked_mse = K.sqrt(K.sum(masked_squared_error, axis=-1) / K.maximum(K.sum(mask_true, axis=-1), 1))
        return masked_mse
```

the model

```
model = deep_model(train, layers, activation, last_activation, dropout, regularizer_encode, regularizer_decode)
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001), loss=masked_mse, metrics=[masked_rmse_clip] )
model.summary()
```

```
data_valid =(train, validate)
```

```
hist_model = model.fit(x=train, y=train,
                  epochs=100,
                  batch_size=128,
                  validation_data= data_valid, verbose=2, shuffle=True)
```

i get this output after 100 epoch

```
Epoch 100/100
48/48 - 6s - loss: 0.9418 - masked_rmse_clip: 0.8024 - val_loss: 0.9853 - val_masked_rmse_clip: 0.8010
```

I want something like this for the MAE. so i need help with the `loss` and `metrics` function for MAE.